# Using multiple wildcards in jq to select objects in a JSON file

Tags: command-line, json, jq

I have a JSON file with thousands of records line by line in the following structure, with different values.

Example:

```
{"in": 5,"li": [{"st": 1508584161,"abc": 128416626,"ta": 33888}],"usr": {"is": "222108923573880","ie": "222108923573880"},"st2": 1508584161,"ei": {"ev": 0,"rt": 10},"rn": 947794,"st1": 1508584161}
{"in": 5,"li": [{"st": 1508584174,"abc": 128572802,"ta": 33504}],"usr": {"is": "222108923573880","ie": "222108923573880"},"st2": 1508584174,"ei": {"ev": 0,"rt": 19},"rn": 947795,"st1": 0}
{"in": 5,"li": [{"st": 1508584145,"abc": 279682,"ta": 50000}],"usr": {"is": "222108923573880","ie": "222108923573880"},"st2": 1508584145,"ei": {"ev": 0,"rt": 18},"rn": 947796,"st1": 1508584145}
{"in": 5,"li": [{"st": 1508584183,"abc": 1378680,"ta": 49840}],"usr": {"is": "222108923573880","ie": "222108923573880"},"st2": 1508584183,"ei": {"ev": 0,"rt": 10},"rn": 947797,"st1": 1508584186}
{"nt": 4}
```

I am trying to select objects (records) in the JSON file that match the following criteria and output to another file.

st1 is < or = st2

st1 is not 0

st2 is not 0

st1 is less than 2147483647

st2 is less than 2147483647

In the output, the footer of the original file ({"nt": 4}) should also be in the output file, so it can be edited with the new records count

Example of output file:

```
{"in": 5,"li": [{"st": 1508584161,"abc": 128416626,"ta": 33888}],"usr": {"is": "222108923573880","ie": "222108923573880"},"st2": 1508584161,"ei": {"ev": 0,"rt": 10},"rn": 947794,"st1": 1508584161} 
{"nt": 1}
```

I have the following:

```
jq -c 'select((.st1 > 0 and .st2 > 0 and .st1 < .st2) or (.st1 < 214748647 and .st2 < 214748647 and .st1 > 0 and .st2 > 0 and .st1 < .st2)) file.json
```

I have tried various permutations but it is not capturing the correct records.

Comment: the above json is invalid without commas `,` separating objects `... } , {..`.

Comment: Update your question with a VALID json structure

Comment: Another problem: `0002` is not valid in JSON, and neither is `00000000000"` (missing quote?).

Comment: Updated the structure.

Comment: @Booboo, still invalid, all objects should be items of an array. Otherwise, the above is just a text lines containing separate independent (therefore unrelated) objects

Comment: `.st1 <=  .st2`  /there is no record with `.st1 < .st2`

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify: (1) your example data doesn't contain any records that actually match your criteria, please make an input example with matching and non-matching records, and write an example how the output should look like. (2) What do you mean by "select the footer"? Always? For files where all records match the criteria? For files where some records match the criteria? In addtion to the matching records. As you can see, an output example is important.

Comment: I don't understand why st1=1508584161 in your output file is supposed to be less than 214748647. The number 1'508'584'161 is clearly greater than 214'748'647. So your output file doesn't match your conditions.

Comment: @dirkt I have updated it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the correct numbers, a straightforward translation of you conditions works:

```
$ jq -c 'select(.st1 <= .st2 and 
                .st1 > 0 and .st2 > 0 and 
                .st1 < 2147483647 and .st2 < 2147483647)' file.json 
{"in":5,"li":[{"st":1508584161,"abc":128416626,"ta":33888}],"usr":{"is":"222108923573880","ie":"222108923573880"},"st2":1508584161,"ei":{"ev":0,"rt":10},"rn":947794,"st1":1508584161}
{"in":5,"li":[{"st":1508584145,"abc":279682,"ta":50000}],"usr":{"is":"222108923573880","ie":"222108923573880"},"st2":1508584145,"ei":{"ev":0,"rt":18},"rn":947796,"st1":1508584145}
```

Note the closing `'`, and no double parenthesis. I don't understand why you split the conditions into two `and` clauses connected by `or`, that's not what your conditions say.

Anyway, that captures the correct records; now we only have to add the footer. That's easiest with an additional step, shortening the select clause from above for brevity:

```
jq -c 'select ...' file.json > out.json
printf '{"nt":%i}\n' `wc -l < out.json` >> out.json
```

I guess one can also do it with a complicated `jq` expression, but I didn't try that.